# After Delete Data Macro

Tags: ms-access

I am running into a problem doing something very simple with MS Access data macros.  When a record row is deleted from T_Roster, I want it copied to t_Deleted.  I know there are a plethora of other and better ways to accomplish this however, the requirements for this are such that a data macro is required.  The end user/manager does not want me to add columns to the roster table or use a form (both of which I had initially suggested). That said, I have been scouring the internet for a solution and see that this question has been answered however, I have not been able to get the simple macro to work on my end.  I have finally worked up the nerve to ask the question here *again* so please be kind.

There are only 2 tables in this DB.  t_Deleted and T_Roster

I have attached a screen shot of what my current macro looks like.  In the interests of keeping things simple, I only want the "OCIO_Name" to copy over for now.  I assume that if this test works, the rest of the fields will not be an issue.

Table properties are as follows:

[T_Roster Table Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWTjN.png)

[t_Deleted Table Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klbjJ.png)

Macro in T_Roster:

[T_Roster AfterDelete Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEBwW.png)

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with what they see?

*edit*  Does not work means that t_Deleted is not updated when I delete a record from T_roster.

Comment: "Does not work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Better to include info in question as text, not images. What is "[Old]" - form name?

Comment: @June7, [Old]. was the syntax that was used for a similar example on this site.  I used [Old].[OCIO_Name] as well as [T_Roster].[OCIO_Name] and neither line was able to do what I needed. I did not get an error message.  I am not using forms in this instance.  Tables only. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, did a test with the [Old] reference and that worked.

Comment: How have you have been able to get this to work and I have not. Same syntax, yes?

Comment: Yes, looks same. Do you have fields set as required in t_Deleted? Is any record created at all, even with all blank fields?

Comment: Ah ha!  I did not set all of the fields.  In my attempt to 'simplify' things it appears that all of the fields need to be set in order for this to work.  I appreciate your help @June7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields set as required will prevent creating new record unless data is provided for them. Either don't set as required or provide data.